# Nginx timeout only for subdomain

Tags: nginx, dns, nginx-config

I have a problem with my Nginx configuration, I'm able to access a domain, but unable to access a "custom" subdomain of a given DNS.

[www.myDomain.com](http://www.myDomain.com) => works perfectly

test.myDomain.com => works perfectly

test.myDomain2.com => ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

I have an entry in my DNS for all the mentioned address for the same server IP, and when I ping them, they both works well.
[www.myDomain2.com](http://www.myDomain2.com) is a website an another domain, and I already have some subdomain redirected to other servers.

This is my config right now.
If I replace test.myDomain2.com by [www.myDomain.com](http://www.myDomain.com) or test.myDomain2.com it's working (so link beetween sites-enable and available seems to be ok).

```
    server {
             listen 80;
             listen [::]:80;
             root /var/www/myDomain.com/html;
             index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

             server_name test.myDomain2.com;

             location / {
             try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
           }
   }
```

No SSL involved, it's the next step !

Pretty sure I'm missing something here, but I'm unable to find the solution... A little help will be really appreciated !

édit: more information, maybe not Nginx but DNS related, but since the pings are working I'm lost..

Comment: You say "no SSL involved", but could the browser be trying to connect to `https://test.myDomain2.com` because of HSTS headers from `myDomain2.com`?

Comment: Thx for the answer, but I'm not really sure how I can check that...
In my browser, I have the http, and it's just an example page with index.html and nothing inside ("hello world"). MyDomain1 is on the same page when it work.

Comment: Test using `curl` rather than a browser.

Comment: Ok... it's working with curl... Thanks, but now I'm lost why it's not working with the browser and glad it's working with this !
I guess the point is my main url have a SSL certificate and the issue is between Nginx not parameter for SSL and an existing SSL certificate for the main domain ?
(I'm a backend c# dev... I play with linux and Nginx but that's really not my cup of tea (for the moment !))

Comment: Browser's cache things, like [HSTS headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) which tell the browser not to use `http` when connecting to a given domain including its subdomains.

Comment: Thank you that was very helpfull !